# have to keep manually clearing cache in joomla

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla3.3

I am working on a Joomla 3.3.6 site and after making changes to articles I have to keep manually clearing the cache
This was not the case before we had issues server side
Is their something I can do

My system settings are:

- cache off
- cache handler file Time 15

Please help its driving me crazy
Thanks
E

Comment: Added relevant tags, reformat text for readability

Comment: Are you sure that the cache is off? Maybe your configuration file is not writable. Can you open the `configuration.php` file and check the value of `$caching` attribute? The correct value should be `public $caching = '0';`

Comment: Also, create a backup and update your site to the last version J3.4.8.